# Problem with filtering collection, using Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

I try to filter collection of objects that have collection field, using Stream API:

```
@Override
public void method (List<Flight> flightList) 
{
List<Flight> trueFlights = flightList.forEach(flight -> flight.getSegments().stream().filter(segment -> segment.getArrivalDate().isBefore(segment.getDepartureDate())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
return trueFlights;
}
```

But it does not compile:

> Error:(32, 27) java: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to
> java.util.List

Segment:

```
class Segment {
    private final LocalDateTime departureDate;

    private final LocalDateTime arrivalDate; 
    //..getter setter
```

Flight:

```
class Flight {
    private final List<Segment> segments;
   //.. getter setter
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't arrivalDate always before departureDate ? What's the intention of this code, if you ignore compilation error for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be looking for `filter` operation over a `Stream`. That would further require you to include a predicate, which is possible with the use of terminal operations `anyMatch`, `allMatch` over the inner stream.

For example, if you want to include input flights to `trueFlights` if **any** of its segment satisfies the condition that the arrival date is before departure date, you could perform `anyMatch`:

```
List<Flight> trueFlights = flightList.stream()
        .filter(flight -> flight.getSegments().stream()
                .anyMatch(segment -> segment.getArrivalDate().isBefore(segment.getDepartureDate())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What you did incorrectly on the other hand was to make use of `forEach` which has a `void` return type and then trying to collect elements further from it.